# Access application visibleViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm wondering how I could access the UIApplication's visibleViewController?

I've tried such things as this, but they aren't working:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navigationController] visibleViewController];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access like this:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
UIViewController *visibleViewController =  [[appDelegate.yourNavigationController viewControllers]lastObject];
```